# Creating a rectangle chart with D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am trying to make a d3 javascript that creates a rectangle whose color depends on a data set. All of the rectangles are adjacent to each other like:

```
         [][][][][][]
         [][][][][][]
```

I got my script to work to create rectangles for all of my data, but it overflows like:

```
          [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
```

How can I create width and height properties for my d3 script so it looks more like

```
        [][][][]
        [][][][]
        [][][][]
```

Here is my script:

```
    <script>
         //for whatever data set
         var data = [];
         //Make an SVG Container
     var svgContainer = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
                                 .data(data)
                                 .enter().append("svg")
                                 .attr("width", 38)
                                 .attr("height", 25);

    //Draw the rectangle
   var rectangle = svgContainer.append("rect")
                     .attr("x", 0)
                     .attr("y", 5)
                     .attr("width", 38)
                     .attr("height", 25);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `x` and `y` properties.

```
.attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return 5 + (i%itemPerLine) * widthRect;
})
.attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 5 + Math.floor(i/itemPerLine) * heightRect;
})
```

(itemPerLine is the number of `rect` per line)

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ngdvpuf/) as example