# Printing x number of elements per line with javascript and d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to print x number of rectangles per line with d3.js

```
        var rectangle = svgContainer.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect")
       .attr("x", function(d,i){ return i*5})
       .attr("y", function(d,i){ return i+1})
       .attr("width", 50)
       .attr("height", 50)
```

I know I need to modify the y attribute, but I feel like I'm blindly changing values until my rectangles print like

```
 [][][][][][]
 [][][][][][]
 [][][][][][]
```

instead of

```
      [[][[][[[][[][[][[]
```

or

```
      []
        []
          []
            []
```

Can I have some insight on how to come up with a formula to print accordingly?

Thank you

Comment: Not really, it did show some positive results but it still prints all of the rectangles in 1 line or meshes multiple rectangles into one spot.

Comment: Yeah! That's what I was looking for with some slight modification. You probably came up with it pretty easily haha, but may I ask how you came to your solution so I can understand for next time?

Comment: I just answer this kind a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39589423/6210816)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this...

```
    var rectangle = svgContainer.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d,i){ return (i%5) * 60})
   .attr("y", function(d,i){ return Math.floor(i / 5) * 60})
   .attr("width", 50)
   .attr("height", 50)
```

Your rects are height and width 50 so the 60 should ensure some gaps between them. 50 will result in no gaps and less than 50 overlapping rectangles.

% is the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) we want the remainder after dividing by 5.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation :)